# In a SpringBoot project with MVC REST API is returning 406 response

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I am working on a SpringBoot project, that uses the regular MVC mechanism to expose the REST APIs.

In one particular GET API, I am getting 406 HTTP Response.

Here is how my Controller method looks:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/analysis/detail/{analysisId}")
    public ResponseEntity<AnalysisDetailResponse> getAnalysisDetails(
            @PathVariable @NotNull Long analysisId) throws BusinessException {
        AnalysisDetailResponse analysisDetailResponse = analysisService.getAnalysisDetailsByAnalysisId(analysisId);
//        return ResponseEntity.ok(analysisService.getAnalysisDetailsByAnalysisId(analysisId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(analysisDetailResponse);
    }
```

The AnalysisDetailResponse is created using Lombok (which is working flawlessly in case of other APIs)

```
@Builder
@ToString
public class AnalysisDetailResponse {

    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private AnalysisStatus state;

    private String failedSummary;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Valid
    private List<PostDetail> posts;

    @Builder
    @ToString
    private static class PostDetail {

        @NotNull
        private Long id;

        @NotNull
        private float score;

        @NotNull
        private String body;

        private List<String> childBodyList;
    }
}
```

I've verified the contents of the entire Response object and it seems to be perfect. However, the response is always 406.

I need the response in JSON format, hence, explicit mentioning of the response type isn't really necessary IMO.

Nevertheless, I tried adding the below content to the @GetMapping annotation, but found no luck:

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

A majority of relevant posts are suggesting to add the `jackson-mapper-asl` and `jackson-core-asl` libraries. I tried it, but that didn't make any difference

Please note, it's just this particular API that's causing issues. There are other APIs defined in the same Controller that are working fine.

Kindly suggest....

**Update:**
I am trying to hit the API using Postman and I did try adding the **Accept** Header parameter explicitly. No luck with it

Comment: How are you calling the endpoint? Do you get any exception in your logs?

Comment: Did you add an `Accept` header in your HTTP request?
`Accept: */*`

Comment: @JoãoDias For Now I'm trying to invoke using Postman with debug mode enabled on my IDE. I can see the control moving without any concerns all the way till the Controller Method exit. The Response Object as well is loaded appropriately.
No Exceptions reported in the logs

Comment: @athom Yes I did try that on Postman. BTW Postman adds it automatically. I did try adding it explicitly and also tried specifying Application/json, nothing worked

Comment: What if you try something simpler. Something like `ResponseEntity<String>` instead of `ResponseEntity<AnalysisDetailResponse>`. This is not what you need but at least we could learn if the issue could be with the serialization of `AnalysisDetailResponse`.

Comment: @JoãoDias That was a good suggestion. I replaced it with String and hardcoded a sample String value. It is coming through.

Comment: No try with `ResponseEntity<AnalysisDetailResponse>` again but this time add `@JsonIgnore` to `private AnalysisStatus state;` and `private List<PostDetail> posts;`. Let us know if it still works. If it does, remove one of the `@JsonIgnore` and try to find the "guilty" one. Let us know which one it is.

Comment: @JoãoDias Extremely weird observation. I just replaced the String with my Response DTO based on your suggestion and placed a debugger breakpoint on the very first line of the controller method.
In the Variables section of the Debugger window, I see this error message:
`((HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException)ex).detailMessage=Cannot find local variable 'ex'`

This is 100% not a loose thread from my end, I've triple, quadruple checked it! Perhaps this is a hint towards the actual root cause

Comment: Are you getting your `AnalysisDetailResponse` from the service or did you instantiate it on your own? So that we can learn if the issue is in the Controller or in the Service.

Comment: @JoãoDias I'm constructing the Response object in the service layer and returning it back to the Controller. BTW what do you think about the `((HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException)ex).detailMessage=Cannot find local variable 'ex'` exception in the comment above?

Comment: I can't really tell anything from that exception. In that case, try to build the `AnalysisDetailResponse` directly in the Controller instead of calling the real method from the Service. So that we understand where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get this working eventually by updating the Response object class's definition.
Lombok was been used and I had applied the [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) annotation to the Response class as well as the static inner class. The motive was to club multiple Lombok annotations into one
Replacing the `@Data` annotation with a more verbose set including `@NoArgsConstructor, @AllArgsConstructor, @Getter, @Setter` resolved the issue.

So, one or more of these Lombok annotations was the real culprit in this scenario:
`@ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @RequiredArgsConstructor`